# How to extract Java class API outline to textfile?

Tags: java, api, interface, extract

How could one export the outline of a Java class to a plain text file?

Something similar to the Outline View in Eclipse, but in a text file. Similar to extracting the interface, but suffeciently more basic.

I've tried to search for such a tool but couldn't find it. I would prefer if extracting the outline could be automated, eg. run the tool from a script.

Comment: Found a solution but if you know an other one with some pros it'd be welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a built-in tool that comes close (bit of an overkill but works). Provided you can compile your program, you can use [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html), the *Java Class File Disassembler* to extract the outline for a class. For example if you have `FooBar.class`, you can do

```
javap FooBar
```

to see the fields and methods at the package's visibility level or

```
javap -private FooBar
```

to see all of the outline. The docs have other options.

**WARNING** Ed Staub [warns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5649931/611007) about potential caveats, you should expect that some situations, probably `maybe annotations, inner classes, something like that` would *not* be handled correctly.

**Availability:** I haven't checked, but the `javap` seems to be available *at least* since **1.5 JDK**.