# Create Mixin without using interfaces

Tags: java, mixins, cglib

In Java, I have some legacy classes (from 3rd party library which I cannot edit) that to not `implement` any interfaces, but for which I would like to create a mixin.

I have looked at [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib) for creating mixins, but [this tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/cglib-missing-manual?page=0,1) states that

> [cglib Mixins](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/cglib/proxy/Mixin.html) allow the combination of several objects into a single object. However, in order to do so, those objects **must be backed by interfaces**

So does anyone know how to create a mixin of two concrete classes, neither of which implement any interfaces?

---

I had been thinking about using bytecode generation to automatically [extract an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622633/automated-way-to-extract-interfaces-from-a-java-class) from a concrete class that I could then just feed into cglib, but I have no idea how to do that either...

Comment: IMO you are better off selectively rewriting or rewriting the legacy classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for anything fancy, just a bit of dull donkey work.

Create the interfaces you'd like to program against, then create concrete classes that implement them using the legacy library.

You can now create mixins using cglib if you really want to, but more importantly you can develop your app without making it strongly dependent on the legacy 3rd party library.